# header sticky is getting flickered when a slight scroll is present in window

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my site I am making header to get sticky its somewhat working good but only the problem is if my window have a slight scroll and i don't have any data then the page will flicker or if until the data isn't get loaded then it will get flickered.
Could someone help me for this?

```
     window.onscroll = function() {stickyHeader()};

      function stickyHeader() {
        var header = document.getElementById("CC-wr-headerWidget")
        if(!document.getElementById("CC-wr-headerWidget")){
           return;
        }
        var sticky = 100;           
        if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
          $('.promobar-1').css('opacity', 0);
          header.classList.add("state-collapsed");
        } else {
          $('.promobar-1').css('opacity', 1);
          header.classList.remove("state-collapsed");
          header.classList.remove("state-not-collapsed");
        }
      }
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you prove a working example of the problem

Comment: Please post this in jsFiddle or codepen